# One-Way Car Rental from Yerevan to Tbilisi

Tags: international-travel, car-rentals, georgia-country, armenia, evn

I would like to rent a car in Yerevan airport, drive it through Armenia, go to Georgia and leave the car in Tbilisi.

Are there any companies who offer that kind of service?

Answer (score 6):

Hertz does, although I haven't tried myself. You can check [Hertz's Armenian website](http://www.hertz.am/) <sup>(in English)</sup>, where you'll also get the price and be able to book this exact service.

[Hertz's Terms and Conditions](http://www.hertz.am/en/Terms.aspx) even has a special section on renting in One Direction specifically for Georgia.

Answer (score 4):

From my experience I will like to advise you [NANIKO car rental in Armenia](http://naniko.am). You can rent a car in Yerevan and leave it in Tbilisi. 
Also as I compared early (5 month ago) NANIKO was cheapest, so highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I used the service of the Armenian car rental company: http://caravan.am/

I paid them to bring a Lada Niva to Tbilisi. From where I would drive in Georgia and Armenia. At the end I brought the car back to their office in Yerevan.

They provided me with the required car documents to cross the border myself from Georgia to Armenia.